# c# array index type checking

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, compilation

Okay I came across this in some code that a co-worker has just started to support.  I've never done anything like this and wouldn't but I was amazed that the compiler did not flag it as an error.

Basically you can see the "strange" behavior with this little snippet:

`array[3/4] = 3;`

This is allowed even though 3/4, I would think, would return a double.
If you change it to:

`array[3.0/4] = 3;`

You do get a compiler error.

I'm assuming the first doesn't create a compiler error because it does integer division and returns an integer.

Comment: I hope you change this code. (I assume the original code is using variables and not hard-coded 3/4.) This is an invitation for bugs. I wish I could unsee it.

Comment: The original code was actually this array[variable * 3/4] and it did do what was required but I don't like it and would have never coded it up that way myself.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if both parts are integer - the compiler performs an integer division.
You get

```
3 / 4 = 0
```

When you try to divide double by an integer - you get a double result, which is not a valid index of array.

Comment: You can easily verify with this `(3/4).GetType()`, which will be `System.Int32`.